# Unity3d: how to detect click within an area

Tags: unity-game-engine

In a Unity3d  application am trying to detect a click in a certain squared area of the current camera. Is there any way to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this not what you're looking for?

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html

** EDIT **

```
using UnityEngine;

public class example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        // Left-half of the screen.
        Rect bounds = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width/2, Screen.height);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && bounds.Contains(Input.mousePosition))
        {
            Debug.Log("Left!");            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is but conditioned to Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) which corresponds to the mouse left click

Comment: This didn't work for me until I used Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y for the the y mouse position. For some reason the origin of a rect is top left, whilst the origin of the mouse is bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

I also use this code piece to detect if the cursor in Game View.

```
Vector2 mPos = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();
if (mPos.x > 0 && mPos.x < Screen.width && mPos.y > 0 && mPos.y < 
Screen.height)
{
    DoSomeMethods();
}
```

But i feel something is still not like i want. :)