# Unity 2D Touch on one side of screen to run a script?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play, touch

I am making a Unity Game for Android devices. It is very basic, and it has a very simple concept. I want it so when I press on the right side of the screen, my main object runs the C# script

```
transform.Rotate(0, 0, 5f);
```

and when you press on the left side of the screen it runs this code on the main object:

```
transform.Rotate(0, 0, -5f);
```

Does anyone know how to do this? If you need any more information I will be happy to give it to you. Thank you.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Unity3d: how to detect click within an area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111821/unity3d-how-to-detect-click-within-an-area). Please do some own research before asking here. Stack overflow is ment for help with specific coding issues not for asking for tutorials or complete solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the touch on the screen like this,

```
 Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
```

After that you can detect the touch position in **Update** method,

```
touch.position;
```

Thus, you are able to control with if else block and do whatever you want,

```
if(touch.position < smth){
  transform.Rotate(0, 0, 5f);
}else{
  transform.Rotate(0, 0, -5f);
}
```